# Capistrano & Puma, configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

When deploying with Capistrano and use it to start the puma server you just include `require 'puma/capistrano'` and it does the magic when using `cap deploy` etc.

But how do i configure the puma server? I mean, let's say I want to change how many workers, cluster mode etc.

**Solution:** Found this in puma/capistrano.rb

```
def config_file
    @_config_file ||= begin
      file = fetch(:puma_config_file, nil)
      file = "./config/puma/#{puma_env}.rb" if !file && File.exists?("./config/puma/#{puma_env}.rb")
      file
    end
  end
```

So I guess I can just put a config file in that directory and it will work.

```
/config/puma/production.rb
```

Comment: please do add an answer since you've found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Found this in puma/capistrano.rb

```
def config_file
    @_config_file ||= begin
      file = fetch(:puma_config_file, nil)
      file = "./config/puma/#{puma_env}.rb" if !file && File.exists?("./config/puma/#{puma_env}.rb")
      file
    end
  end
```

Just add the options in this file, if it's production, otherwise change the file name to appropriate environment.

```
/config/puma/production.rb
```